# Mounting network drive works in DOS, but breaks in Cygwin. Why?

Tags: window, cygwin, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm using VirtualBox to set up a windows 2008 server. I'd like to add a shared folder, but am running into problems.

Running this in DOS works:

```
net use t: \\vboxsrv\v-root
```

But in Cygwin:

```
$ net use t: "\\vboxsrv\v-root"
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

I've also tried these:

```
$ net use t: \\vboxsrv\v-root
$ net use t: \\\\vboxsrv\\v-root
```

And I've tried creating a bat script containing the working DOS command, and executing it from cygwin. They all fail with the same error.

I need to do it through Cygwin, because I access the system via SSH, and land in a Cygwin environment. If there is any way to "break out" of cygwin temporarily from within Cygwin, that might be a way to go..

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably better on superuser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a folder somewhere, like:

```
$> mkdir -p /mnt/t
```

Now you can us the mount program in cygwin, like so:

```
$> mount \\vboxsrv\v-root /mnt/t
```

Easy as 1,2,3 :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows root path is typically found somehwere under `/cygdrive/`. Try something like

```
$ net use t: /cygdrive/c/vboxsrv/v-root
```

Answer (score 0):

For this error,

!) Give full rights to Shared folder at Host side using "**sudo chmod 777 -R /home/username/Shared**"    (**Shared** is a folder name which we have to be shared.)

!!) Open Guest in Virtualbox, before accessing shared folder.: "**Install Guest Additions**"  From Menu

!!!)  Click **START**, Right click on **Computer** , Select "**Map Network Drive**"

!V)  In that select any drive and bellow that type folder "**\Yourhostipaddress\Shared**". Bellow that select "connect with credential"   (**Yourhostipaddress** is a HOST IP ADDRESS   and **Shared** is Shared folder name at host side. )

V) Click On connect button. It will ask you host username and password.

```
 Put **USERNAME** Properly like "**XXXXXXXX-PC**".
```

V!) It will map with shared drive successfully !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

If still getting error, Put comments bellow this.